# Django admin change site title based on client IP

Tags: django, admin

I'd like to change the Django site title based on where the client is from (it's an internal site, so it will be from a few basic IP ranges)

I've implemented a middleware that checks for a Boolean session variable (checked_ip).

If checked_ip is exists, everything else is skipped, so it should only be checked once per session.

If checked_ip doesn't exist, it then looks at the header to determine the IP address and sets another Boolean session variable based on the address (eg site1_ip)

Then in the admin templates I override the relevant base template to change the site title depending on the appropriate session variable (eg site1_ip, or site2_ip etc).

I was hoping not to create too much overhead. Is there a more efficient/better way of doing this ?

Comment: I don't hang out on CodeReview so apologies if what I'm recommending is off-topic there (be sure to check first!), but based on the text of your question it seems that you should post the code of your middleware on codereview.stackexchange.com to get these recommendations.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist If OP is willing to include actual code (stub code and example code are not allowed on Code Review), it would be a good fit.

Comment: Thanks, I may do that. But I'm just wondering if there's a smarter way to do it instead of middleware inspecting each request

Answer (score 0):

Since Django 1.7 there's a property named `AdminSite.site_title` (see [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.AdminSite.site_title)), so you can probably use that.

Comment: Sure, but this won't let me change the title based on the client ?

Comment: @mcrsam maybe I am missing something, but I thought that's just a matter of setting the value from middleware into the attribute (?) And maybe you have to inherit the `AdminSite` in your project.